# MongoDB creating index on a new field

Tags: mongodb, indexing, ttl

I need to create a TTL Index in MongoDB and for that, I'm adding a new field "last_modified". I'm using the latest Python and pymongo in case this makes any difference.
After reading [information on sparse and non-sparse indexes](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-sparse/) I understand that all documents that do not have "last_modified" will have this field added with the null value.

Is there a way to set some default value instead of null for those documents?

Alternatively, I'll have to update all documents in all DB instances using some migration function, but I would really like to do it clean...

Thanks in advance for any links or ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I understand that all documents that do not have "last_modified" will have this field added with the null value.

No this is not true, sparse indexes just index documents where the field ***exists***. documents without this field will just be out of the index converage.

> Is there a way to set some default value instead of null for those documents? ...  I'll have to update all documents in all DB instances ... to do it clean...

You have to run an update, there is no magic solution. Not sure why doing this is "not clean".

The update is super simple:

```
// this query will allow you to execute the update even if you started streaming new events with this field.
db.collection.updateMany({ last_modified: {$exists: false} }, { $set: { last_modified: defaultValue }})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That answers my question totally)
They will be added as null because the index is going to be non-sparse.
I feel like it is not really clean as I need this code only once for each DB instance, after that the code is going to be absolutely dead and never used.
P.S. Can't cast a vote up yet(